# Object reference not set to an instance of object - BaseStream.Seek

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In the below code for BaseStream.Seek, I am getting runtime error NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. Object reference not set to an instance of object.

How can I resolve this?

```
public void GoButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    IAsyncResult ar = DoSomethingAsync(strURL, strInput);
    Session["result"] = ar;
    Response.Redirect("wait1.aspx");
}

private IAsyncResult DoSomethingAsync(string strURL, string strInput)
{
    DoSomethingDelegate doSomethingDelegate = new DoSomethingDelegate(DoSomething);
    IAsyncResult ar = doSomethingDelegate.BeginInvoke(strURL, strInput, new AsyncCallback(MyCallback), null);
    return ar;
}

private delegate void DoSomethingDelegate(string strURL, string strInput);

private void MyCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    AsyncResult aResult = (AsyncResult)ar;
    DoSomethingDelegate doSomethingDelegate = (DoSomethingDelegate)aResult.AsyncDelegate;
    doSomethingDelegate.EndInvoke(ar);
}

private void DoSomething(string strURL, string strInput)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine("{0} ", MethodCall(strURL, strInput));
        m_streamWriter.Flush();
        m_streamWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting m_streamWriter?

Comment: I am initializing at the top of the class    private static FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\Temp\\Data.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    private static StreamWriter m_streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) 
    { 
        m_streamWriter.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End); 
        m_streamWriter.WriteLine("{0} ", MethodCall(strURL, strInput)); 
    } 
    m_streamWriter.Flush(); 
    m_streamWriter.Close();
```

Try to move m_streamWriter.Close out of loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're closing the stream and then trying to call Seek() on it in the next iteration of your for loop - that looks a good candidate as the source of your exception

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve but commenting out the line which closes the stream will prevent the exception from being thrown

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `Seek` on and `WriteLine` to a closed stream.

EDIT: Oh, Ian was faster.